# GetElementsByTagName ƒ item() { [native code] } - What is this?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

With the code below

```
<ul>
  <li>Rice</li>
  <li>Coffee</li>
  <li>Beans</li>
</ul>

<script>
    var elem = document.getElementsByTagName('li')
    for (var i in elem) {
        console.log(elem[i])
    }
</script>
```

I see five results, as follows.

```
<li>Rice</li>
<li>Coffee</li>
<li>Beans</li>
ƒ item() { [native code] }
ƒ namedItem() { [native code] }
```

What in the world are the last two items?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`for-in` loop iterates over all *enumerable* properties of an object. The `.getElementsByTagName()` method returns an [HTMLCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection) which can be iterated over. The thing is that the `HTMLCollection` has additional properties (methods): `item()` and `namedItem()` which apparently are *enumerable* and this is why `for-in` iterates over them.

To avoid that, you can use a standard `for-loop`:

```
var elem = document.getElementsByTagName('li');
for (var i = 0; i < elem.length; i++) {
    console.log(elem[i]);
}
```

You can read about properties descriptors (e.x. *enumerable*) [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty).

Answer (score 3):

Methods. `elem` is an [`HTMLCollection`](https://www.javascripture.com/HTMLCollection), not an array, it has those methods, and they are historically enumerable.

Don't use `for in`. `for in` iterates over all keys of an object.

You can use `for of` instead:

```js
for (const item of elem) {
  console.log(item) 
}
```

...or convert it to an array using `Array.from(elem)`, then you can use all the regular array functionalities with it.

You can also go the old-fashioned way and just iterate from 0 to < length:

```js
for (let i = 0; i < elem.length; i++) {
  console.log(elem[i])
}
```